# ¿Como puedo permitir las conexiones desde otra IP local en XAMPP?

Tags: xampp

como puedo permitir las conexiones a mi página local en XAMPP desde otro dispositivo de la misma red local?

Desde mi equipo donde tengo XAMPP puedo acceder perfectamente pero desde otro equipo conectado a la misma red no puedo acceder.

Como puedo solucionar esto? Gracias

Comment: ¿Podrías indicar la IP que tiene el equipo con XAMPP y qué URL has probado para acceder a él desde los equipos remotos? Es probable que simplemente necesites agregar una excepción en el cortafuegos que tengas instalado en el equipo (el de Windows, el que tenga tu antivirus o cualquier otro que tengas instalado).

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente con la IP de la PC que está corriendo el servidor (XAMPP). Para chequearlo puedes ejecutar en la terminal:

**Windows:**

`$ ipconfig`

**Linux o Mac:**

`$ ifconfig`

Luego en otro dispositivo podrás ingresar poniendo la IP de tu PC en el navegador.

Comment: Gracias, pero no puedo acceder no me acepta la conexion así

Comment: De casualidad tenés configurado una virtual host?

Answer (score 1):

La forma más sencilla es localizar to ip local con el comando: **ipconfig**
supongamos un resultado: **192.168.10.23**

Desde otro ordenador en el buscador pones: **http://192.168.10.23:80**
es importante incluir el puerto en el que escucha tu servidor el puerto 80 es el utilizado por defecto con XAMPP.

**Si no especificas el puerto no funciona.**